# How to insert input text into image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to develop extension for magento which help to create custom t-shirt but i don't know how to do it.I want to provide functionality like this site <s>http://www.inkpixi.com/item/ATV+Repair/A252/329/item.html</s><sup>*Dead link*</sup>

here you enter the name and then name automatically insert to image .i want to provide this exactly but didn't get right matter

Comment: This is done with server-side image processing, not jQuery

Comment: Would not position a <span> above (on top of) the image be enough? At least for starters...

Comment: i am not clear about server-side image processing what do you mean by that,

Answer (score 13):

You can do it so simply with [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas)

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width  = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function sendToCanvas( ob ){
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = ob.fontWeight+' '+ob.fontSize+' '+ob.fontFamily;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = ob.color;
    ctx.fillText(ob.text, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2.5);
  });
  img.src = ob.image;
}

// Defaults
var cvsObj = {
    text       : "stackoverflow",
    image      : "http://i.imgur.com/hqayV16.jpg",
    fontFamily : "Arial",
    fontWeight : "bold",
    fontSize   : "90%",
    color      : "rgba(244, 128, 36, 0.7)"
};

sendToCanvas( cvsObj ); // Send default data on init

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("input", function(){
  cvsObj.text = this.value; // Modify cvsObj text
  sendToCanvas( cvsObj );   // Send custom data on input
});
```

```html
Text: <input id="text" type="text"><br>
```

<sup>*Right click* and *Save as* `:)` !</sup>

Comment: this is different from what i want,i want exactly the same functionality which provided in the given site

Comment: I want to add background-size and background-position to the image because it has cropped inside canvas. I have added styles in sendToCanvas array but it doesn't work. please help!

Comment: @Nishan help you with what exactly?

Comment: Does anyone know how do set a background color INSTEAD of an source image?

Comment: @thobiash You mean to change the Tshirt color?