# convert input text into an image in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery and html I want to show the input text into an image for that I have my markup like this

```
  <div class="text-input-wrap">
    <input type="text" id="text-input"/> <br />
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Preview" />
  </div><!--.text-input-wrap-->
```

I want that when someone will click on Preview after typing the text in input text area then the text should show as an image. For that I hav my jQuery like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#button').click(function() {
    var textvalue = $( "#text-input").val();
    alert(textvalue);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width  = 500;
  canvas.height = 500;
  canvas.style.borderRadius = "15px";
  document.body.appendChild(canvas); // Add canvas to DOM

  // GRAPHICS
  var canvasImage = new Image();

  // GRAPHICS TO CANVAS ///////////////////

  function drawCanvas() {
    ctx.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0);
  }

  function drawText( text ) {
    ctx.font = '90px Calibri';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(70, 70, 255, 0.7)';
    ctx.fillText(text, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
  }
  drawCanvas();
  drawText('textvalue'); 
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Here the alert text is showing the value of text in right but when the text is converting into an image it is not showing the input text? So can someone tell me where is the wrong part? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks..

Comment: first of all: Remove the drawCanvas() function and the canvasImage. You don't need an image to draw text on a canvas. canvasImage is also an empty image and I don't know what happens if you draw an unassigned image to a canvas. Anything on the JS console? Ah: And remove the single quotes from the call to drawText: `drawText(textvalue);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert text into image using jquery ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875638/how-to-convert-text-into-image-using-jquery) `:)` Rest I hope link will suffice your need: **Demo** : http://jsbin.com/ipohok/3/edit