# Edit text on canvas HTML5 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I know canvas can't editing text from field.

I try to make this http://jsfiddle.net/0n60y65o/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = $('#cEditor')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var newTxt = 'Your text here';

    createTxt();

    $('input[data-selector="inputName"]').bind('change', function () {
        var newVal = $(this).val();
        changeTxt(newVal);
    });

    function createTxt() {
        context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(newTxt, 0, 0);
    }

    function changeTxt(newVal) {
        newTxt = newVal;
        context.save();
        context.fillText(newTxt, 0, 0);
        context.restore();
    };
});
```

but it can make new text on canvas not change a text on canvas.

I hope someone tell me workflow and component for build editor this site 
http://customerscanvas.com/demos/Editor.aspx?header=1-sided%20Business%20Card&design=BusinessCard1&downloadEnabled=true&backgroundButtonEnabled=true&rectEllipseButtonsEnabled=false (sorry I'm not spam, it's for example live site)
On that site, you can change style/edit text, add a text, add a image etc.

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875638/how-to-convert-text-into-image-using-jquery and a live demo: http://jsbin.com/kexuz/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the canvas, which can be done be resetting the width, and redraw the text, so basically you could just do the same thing as when you're first creating it, everytime the text changes, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[data-selector="inputName"]').on('input', createTxt).trigger('input');

    function createTxt() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('cEditor');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.fillText(this.value, 0, 0);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0n60y65o/3/)

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, but if case like on example site (in question), add some text, and then edit a text. Your solution is good but it can make new image on canvas not change it.

Comment: @itx use canvas layers?!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : you mean, build like this [layer with kineticJs](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-layer-management-with-kineticjs/) and for change a element using like this http://jsbin.com/kelawipela/1/edit?html,js,output ?

Comment: @itx - I'm guessing Roko means layering multiple canvas elements on top of each other to easily redraw some parts without having to redraw everything